# "Invalid Syntax" on while-if-elif?

Tags: python-3.x

I recently got into python3.x and want to have a script where a random number is generated and stored in a variable, the user has to input a number and the script then checks if the number is greater or smaller (or the same) than the generated number and answers accordingly. 
So far I got

```
import random
n = random.randint(1, 101)
a = input("Please enter your number: ")
while not(int(a) == n):
    if(int(a) > n)
        print("Your number is smaller."):
    elif(int(a) < n)
        print("Your number is greater."):
```

But in this code I get "Invalid Syntax in line 5", the first `if`. How do I get rid of that? Also, how do I loop the whole `while`-block until the number is correct?

Comment: Unrelated, but you should convert `a` to an int only once before the while loop - and you may want to put this in a try/except block to catch conversion errors (hint: try to input a letter instead of a number at the prompt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: Actually you left colon in if and elif at last.

```
import random
n = random.randint(1, 101)
a = input("Please enter your number: ")
while not(int(a) == n):
    if(int(a) > n):
        print("Your number is smaller.")
    elif(int(a) < n):
        print("Your number is greater.")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a colon on line 5 and you have colons on like 6 and 8.
You should read up on a python tutorial somewhere on how the python syntax works, but in general colons are used to denote a new indented block, so whenever you write indented code, it should be preceeded by a colon

Comment: this should be a comment and question should be closed as a typo